# Spark tasks stuck at RUNNING

Tags: apache-spark

I'm trying to run a Spark ML pipeline (load some data from JDBC, run some transformers, train a model) on my Yarn cluster but each time I run it, a couple - sometimes one, sometimes 3 or 4 - of my executors get stuck running their first task set (that'd be 3 tasks for each of their 3 cores), while the rest run normally, checking off 3 at a time.

In the UI, you'd see something like this:
[image: Spark web UI screenshot]

Some things I have observed so far:

- When I set up my executors to use 1 core each with `spark.executor.cores` (i.e. run 1 task at a time), the issue does not occur;
- The stuck executors always seem to be the ones that had to get some partitions shuffled to them in order to run the task;
- The stuck tasks would ultimately get successfully speculatively executed by another instance;
- Occasionally, a single task would get stuck in an executor that is otherwise normal, the other 2 cores would keep working fine, however;
- The stuck executor instances look like everything is normal: CPU is at ~100%, plenty of memory to spare, the JVM processes are alive, neither Spark or Yarn log anything out of the ordinary and they can still receive instructions from the driver, such as "drop this task, someone else speculatively executed it already" -- though, for some reason, they *don't drop it*;
- Those executors never get killed off by the driver, so I imagine they keep sending their heartbeats just fine;

Any ideas as to what may be causing this or what I should try?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**TLDR**: Make sure your code is threadsafe and race condition-free before you blame Spark.

Figured it out. For posterity: was using an thread-unsafe data structure (a mutable HashMap). Since executors on the same machine share a JVM, this was resulting in data races that were locking up the separate threads/tasks.

The upshot: when you have `spark.executor.cores > 1` (and you probably should), make sure your code is threadsafe.

Comment: Curious - how did you figure out it was the thread-unsafe data structure?  Thread-dumping the executors?

Comment: Didn't quite get to that part. I was able to narrow it down to the particular module and, having been bitten in the behind by multithreaded code many a times, I was able to figure it out.

Comment: This is a very nice piece of advise. Thank you

Comment: @ktdrv Did you use spark local mode? Because I am pretty sure that each spark executor use it's own JVM in cluster mode

Comment: I'm pretty sure this was yarn but I'd argue that the mode did not matter in this case either way. The problem was ultimately that there was a race condition in the code running on one of the executors -- separate JVM or not -- that prevented the task from completing. You're correct, however: each executor gets its own JVM.