# Spark: Tasks with zero input takes forever to complete

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, bigdata

Spark 2.2

I have a spark job that reads compressed data from HDFS, applies the ETL logic and writes the output back to HDFS. However, when I see in the spark UI for task level data, some tasks have Input Records / Size marked as 0.0B/6 (i.e 0.0B/N, where N < 100). Also, all other tasks in the stage which have inputs like XX MB completes successfully in sometime, but the tasks with 0.0B as input runs forever thereby leaving the spark job running forever.

I understand that data skew can leave 1 partition way bigger than others and cause straggler tasks. However, I am seeing the opposite behavior - tasks with inputs like 100MB/500MB are getting completed whereas the tasks with 0.0B as input are hung.

Have you seen such behavior? How should I debug and resolve the issue? Any help is appreciated. Thank You!

Eg Spark UI data:

```
Task ID ▴   Address         Status          Input Size / Records  Task Duration
 1          machine:xxxx     Completed         37.0 MB / 63106       2Min 5Sec
 2          machine:xxxx     Running           0.0 B / 64068         20Hrs 50Sec
 3          machine:xxxx     Running           0.0 B / 65045         20Hrs 50Sec
 4          machine:xxxx     Completed         38.1 MB / 64255       3Mins 7Sec
 5          machine:xxxx     Completed         52.3 MB / 82091       9Mins 3Sec
 6          machine:xxxx     Completed         49.1 MB / 79232       10Mins 6Sec
 7          machine:xxxx     Running           0.0 B / 48337         20Hrs 50Sec
 8          machine:xxxx     Running           0.0 B / 59438         20Hrs 50Sec
```

Answer (score 1):

Try running your code on single core for debugging, it could be possible that you are not using thread safe code and your jobs are stuck in race condition. Something like this: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48348624/spark-tasks-stuck-at-running)

Answer (score 0):

Typically this happens because spark is doing something lengthy before it starts actually reading the data. Classically you can trigger this behaviour by recursively searching a really large filesystem, or one that is slow to enumerate. Similarly, waiting on non-clustered database may result in this behaviour. Without seeing your code it is hard to say more.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Nothing fancy in the code, its standard data engg -                              
read raw data (~100GB compressed) --> apply UDFs and filters --> write as parquet

Comment: @SaurabhAgrawal Well, you say it's standard but you're seeing something you've never seen before. Without the code (at least for reading) and a description of how the data is laid out on disk (number of files, format) I can't comment other than to say what I did above.