# Spark Job getting stuck in last tasks while prefix query on BigTable

Tags: java, apache-spark, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-bigtable

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g8cLa.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZVBkc.png)My Spark job is getting stuck frequently in the last task to query Google Cloud BigTable table.

```
Query query = Query.create(tableName).prefix(prefixRowKey);
ServerStream<Row> rowStream = bigtableDataClient.readRows(query);
```

Find below the thread dump when executor is in stuck phase:

[Executor Thread Dump](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g8cLa.png)

[Job (Yarn UI) stuck in last task](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZVBkc.png)

Comment: can you share spark ui stage snapshot

Comment: Hi, it seems that Spark hang waiting for something,... . Could you share more information about your application. Do you have a reproducible example of this issue? Because it would be extremely useful to help you.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @tarun added Yarn UI snapshot

Comment: @Juancki Our spark job runs prefix query on Big Table using BigtableDataClient inside map task. If the data size is too big (> 1MM) the job sometimes (1 out of 4 times) gets stuck on one of the executors and the way out of it is to ssh on the node where the task is stuck and kill yarn process leading the job to fail and thus initiating a retry.

Comment: There are spark users that had race conditions in their code https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48348624/spark-tasks-stuck-at-running. You can test that by setting `park.executor.cores = 1`.

Comment: @Juancki I am running _20 n1-standard-4 nodes_ cluster and have 3 cores per executor. Decreasing the cores will result in slow down which wont be acceptable. But going through other comments on the above thread I can try looking into any piece of code thats not thread safe. I just hope that it's not because of ServerStream as the same code used to work well with Aerospike.

Comment: Yes, the comment was about a way for testing the possibility of race condition in your code.

Comment: This may or may not be related.  This fix in the gax batcher remedied a rare race condition hang that we were seeing and is released as 1.59.1

https://github.com/googleapis/gax-java/pull/1200